# Why is the movie in this blend file, blank?

Tags: python, video

So demonstrating my considerable skill (not) I failed in my attempt to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2W_fQayYcA) tutorial.  Around the 7:45 mark, he says we should be able to press 'P' (to enter game mode) in order to play the video, and well, its not working.

I don't know how the few differences between what the tutorial guy did and I did could cause this, and I clearly have not learned the skills if I can't find out at this point, so  I'd appreciate any help!

The blend file can be found [at pasteall.](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/40861)  Do note that I refer to the folder "resources" available in the zip file in the youtube description.

(Python: Also, if you want to modify the script, copy/paste the character they used to indent, for me, tabs and white-space didn't work.)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: Your path to the movie was wrong i.e. not relative. So while pressing *P* you see the movie. In attached screenshot you will see that I changed the path to *//Resources/Movie.wmv*. "**//**" means that blender starting to looking for you movie at this folder where your .blend file is. I may can upload you the project file, too. Just write a commit.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - but you are technically wrong!  The script has a line (line 52 I believe) that does this for you - the real problem was I *forgot* to capitalize movie.  Still, if it weren't for you, I might have still missed it, so upvote.